# AmCharts 4 - How to use custom ajax response in MapPolygonSeries()

Tags: javascript, arrays, amcharts

I'm testing amcharts 4 map (PieChart() & MapPolygonSeries()) and I have a response.data like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "legal_country": [
        {
            "legal_country": "US",
            "count(*)": 171576
        },
        {
            "legal_country": "GB",
            "count(*)": 130246
        },
        {
            "legal_country": "DE",
            "count(*)": 112459
        },
        {
            "legal_country": "NL",
            "count(*)": 96554
        }
    ]
}
```

I store the legal_country array in two variables:

```
var getAjaxRecords1 = data.legal_country;
var getAjaxRecords2 = data.legal_country;
```

Now for the am4charts.PieSeries() I can access the data and define value and category like this:

```
var chart = am4core.create("lei_pie", am4charts.PieChart);

chart.data = getAjaxRecords2;   

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
series.dataFields.value = "count(*)";
series.dataFields.category = "legal_country";
```

All works fine.

But how can use the data in the MapPolygonSeries()? This does not work:

```
// Create polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
...
polygonSeries.dataFields.value = "count(*)";
polygonSeries.dataFields.category = "legal_country";

polygonSeries.data = getAjaxRecords1;
```

... and I don't find it in the docs: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygonseries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[To tie data to particular `MapPolygon`s, the data item itself needs to have an `id` field that matches the polygon's `id`.](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#In_line_data)

Also, [please note the array assigned to a `MapPolygonSeries.data` gets *mutated*](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Note_about_data_mutation). So you'll probably want to provide a copy of that array so the original works as expected throughout your app.

You can try formatting your data before passing it along to the `MapPolygonSeries`, e.g.:

```js
var mapData = [];
getAjaxRecords1.forEach(function(countryData) {
  // Push a new object to our new array with an appropriate id
  mapData.push(Object.assign( { "id": countryData.legal_country }, countryData ));
});
// Test mutation:
// mapData[0]["count(*)"] = 5;
// getAjaxRecords1[0]["count(*)"]; // 171576, unchanged
polygonSeries.data = mapData;
```

However, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do with this code:

```js
polygonSeries.dataFields.value = "count(*)";
polygonSeries.dataFields.category = "legal_country";
```

What are you expecting that to do? What is it you're trying to achieve with the map series?